# Perl script to read a directory and having file name started by a particular name

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, regex-lookarounds, perl-data-structures

I have a directory containing thousand of file.
Suppose I have 3 pdf files having same name like:

1. sample_Q1.pdf
2. sample_Q2.pdf
3. sample_Q3.pdf

Now I want to find the file list having particular name started with "Sample".

I'm currently using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my $dir = '/home/gaurav/Desktop/CSP';
opendir( DIR, $dir ) or die $!;
while ( my $file = readdir(DIR) ) {

# We only want files
    next unless ( -f "$dir/$file" );

# Use a regular expression to find files ending in .txt
    next unless ( $file =~ /\.pdf$/ );
    print "$file\n";
}

closedir(DIR);
exit 0;
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $dir = '/home/gaurav/Desktop/CSP';

    opendir(DIR, $dir) or die $!;

    while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {

        # We only want files
        next unless (-f "$dir/$file");

        # Use a regular expression to find files ending in .txt
        next unless ($file =~ /\.pdf$/);

        print "$file\n";
    }

    closedir(DIR);
    exit 0;

Comment: I have copied you cored from comment into main text. Please can you check it's still correct?

Comment: What are you having problems with? You already have code to check that the file name ends with ".pdf". It's simple to extend the logic to check that the file name starts with "Sample" as well.

Comment: Actually geetring name i want to make insert in database .i got all name starting with sample that is count 3 .Now i want to use these name to make 3 insert in mysql .Where should i save it to make insert for all three.

Comment: That is an entirely different question, and probably warrants opening a new one.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest that rather than `readdir` what you really want is `glob`. This latter expands a pattern in the same way as the shell does, and returns matches. The reason it's particularly useful is that `readdir` returns file names, where `glob` returns full paths. (e.g. directory too).

E.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my $dir = '/home/gaurav/Desktop/CSP';

foreach my $file ( glob ( "$dir/sample*.pdf" ) ) {
    print $file,"\n";
}
```

if you want to skip any 'non files' there's two approaches:

```
next unless -f $file;
```

Or:

```
foreach my $file ( grep { -f $_ } glob ( "$dir/sample*.pdf" ) )  {
```

But that's probably a moot point unless you've got directories suffixed `.pdf` which would be a bit unusual.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $DirectoryName = '......';

chdir( $DirectoryName ) or die "Can't change directory: $!\n";
my @files = glob( "sample*");
for my $file (@files) {
  print $file,"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give list of all files name which start with *sample* and have extention *.pdf*:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

opendir my $dir, "/home/gaurav/Desktop/CSP" or die "Can't open directory: $!";
my @files = grep { /sample.*\.pdf$/ } readdir $dir;
print "@files";
closedir $dir;
```

Use a `foreach` loop if you want print file names one by one:

```
foreach my $file (@files)
{
    print "$file\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do that like below.

```
$file =~ /^sample.*\.pdf$/i
```

Here 'i' is used for case insensitive. it will search both 'sample' and 'Sample'.

```
while ( my $file = readdir(DIR) ) 
{

      if((-f "$dir/$file" ) && ($file =~ /^sample.*\.pdf$/i))
      {
          print "$file \n";
      }
}
```

Comment: Why not skipping the `else` clause? It doesn't do anything.